# Checking for non-None values

Tags: python, nonetype

Let's say we have two integer or string values and we would like to select the value out of those two which is not None.

```py
val1 = None
val2 = 100
```

The mainstream or conventional way of doing this would be

```py
val = val1 if val1 else val2
or 
val = val1 if val1 is not None else val2
```

But I am unsure why is this approach not used as this yields the same output.

```py
val = val1 or val2
```

The second approach becomes specially much more useful when we have to select a non-null value out of multiple values. So it becomes simply

```py
val = val1 or val2 or val3 or val4
```

Am I missing any underlying concept here?

Comment: Note [`0` and `""` are also false-y](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing), you should probably have `val1 if val1 is not None else val2`. As to why you'd use the conditional vs logical expression, that's going to depend on context and preference.

Comment: _mainstream or conventional way of doing this would be_ - what makes you think so? Note the @jonrsharpe comment - both lines will yield the same result when `val1` is evaluated as False - e.g. 0, empty string, empty containers...

Comment: `val1 if val1 else val2` is indeed exactly equivalent to `val1 or val2`.  I'd consider the `or` version to be more pythonic (it's the exact reason the operator works that way), but it's somewhat unique to Python so not everyone knows it's there.  Another handy trick is `val1 and val1.val2` as a shorthand for `val1.val2 if val1 else None`.

Comment: fantastic insight @jonrsharpe, probably that is why `val1 or val2` is not that common, but rather explicit if else checks are more common

Answer (score 2):

Both are wrong. What you want is something like this:

```
val = val1 if val1 is not None else val2
```

which is correct for

```
val1 = 0
val2 = None
```

(If both values are `None`, you'll have to check for that explicitly to avoid `val = None`, if necessary.)